# Calculating parity in parallel

Tags: c++, c, x86-64, parity

Consider the following code

```
typedef unsigned uint;

uint parity( uint64_t x )
    {
    uint32_t v = x ^ (x >> 32);
    v ^= v >> 16;
    v ^= v >> 8;
    v ^= v >> 4;
    v ^= v >> 2;
    return (uint)(v ^ (v >> 1)) & 1;
    }
```

Is there a way of radically reorganising this code to get a serious improvement due to instruction-level parallelism on say an Intel x86-64 machine?

GCC produced the following code

```
parity(unsigned long):
    mov     rax, rdi
    shr     rax, 32
    xor     eax, edi
    mov     edi, eax
    shr     edi, 16
    xor     eax, edi
    mov     edi, eax
    shr     edi, 8
    xor     eax, edi
    mov     edi, eax
    shr     edi, 4
    xor     eax, edi
    mov     edi, eax
    shr     edi, 2
    xor     eax, edi
    mov     edx, eax 
    shr     eax
    xor     eax, edx 
    and     eax, 1
    ret
```

Comment: What is `(uint)v`?

Comment: If you have SSE4.2: `return _mm_popcnt_u64(x) & 1;`

Comment: I forgot about popcnt - many thanks.

Comment: Be wary of dual tagging with C and C++.  They're different languages and often what is appropriate in one is not appropriate in the other.

Comment: but this _type_ of data-reducing algorithm is just inherently one big serial dependency and there's not much I can do about it? (apart from using the hardware as in popcnt)

Comment: If you're trying to get the parity of a long stream of integers, just XOR them together. Then you only need the to do one reduction at the end. That's also vectorizable.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler - agreed, but the algorithm is the same in D or in C++ or in C, and its more about getting the best out of the machine's ILP if you have any

Comment: @Mysticial - vg point, worthy tip

Comment: That's why you got a "be wary" rather than a "don't", which is the advice I'd normally give.  This time, you can get away with it.  Often, you won't.  Be cautious — or wary.

Comment: God people are fast on this forum, that's one reason why I love it so.

Comment: @Jonathan - agreed

Comment: Should we take the C++ off as being unhelpful?

Comment: Up to you.  Like I said, this time it is OK, and you're unlikely to get downvotes because of the dual tagging.

Comment: Aside: An idea I had to begin with: the change of type to 32-bits is only to save some bytes on the x86-64. I don't expect it to improve the speed at all, unless the saving of a few bytes might help make the code fit into the instruction cache

Comment: The algorithm you've chosen is pretty serial. That said, I can't imagine you are calling this method _once_ or else you wouldn't care about the speed. Assuming you are calling it a lot, you can create a method that does the XOR-fold for several (disjoint, even) integers at once, and operates faster. I assume you've also looked at the [alternatives here](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ParityNaive). The xor-folding one they show seems faster than yours by using a couple of tricks for the last couple lines.

Comment: Yes, I had looked at that page, but I wanted to keep it simple as I only wanted to asked about whether things _have to_ be so serial. I really am not getting any of the wonderful n-way ILP that you can often get nowadays (quite often n=3, even).

Answer (score -3):

In the 32bit world I would write directly in assembler something like `test eax,eax` followed by `SETPO EAX`.

UPDATE 2017-02-06: @EOF is right, the test command sets the parity bit only according the lowbyte.

Comment: That would be a hell of a good plan if you have no popcnt. Could be used on a 64-bit processor too.

Comment: actually a huge lot faster than popcnt too poss?

Comment: @CecilWard: As the first assembler instruction suggests: TEST it! :)

Comment: The parity-flag only considers the parity of the lowest eight bits in the result.

Comment: Thanks for that EOF, I didn't know that and I've never used tests on the parity flag writing x86 assembler otherwise I would have been bitten before now.